# failed to Install Openstack using openstack install script in 14.0.4

Tags: 14.04, openstack

I am new to openstack, while trying to install openstack using the installer script and following the instruction at [Single Installer Guide](http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/single-installer.guide.html). I receive the following error. :

```
administrator@kvrgz-controller:~/.cloud-install$ more commands.log 
INFO • 11-05 23:39:42 [LINE:102, FUNC:<module>] • cloudinstall • cloud-install starting
INFO • 11-05 23:39:42 [LINE:73, FUNC:status_context] • cloudinstall.core • Get started by entering an Openstack password to u
se in your cloud ..
DEBUG • 11-05 23:39:42 [LINE:101, FUNC:_build_widget] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • Num items: 2, items: <BoxAdapter selectable 
flow widget <ListBox selectable box widget> height=2>
DEBUG • 11-05 23:39:54 [LINE:108, FUNC:submit] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • Callback on : OrderedDict([('password', <EditInput 
selectable flow widget>), ('confirm_password', <EditInput selectable flow widget>)])
INFO • 11-05 23:39:54 [LINE:73, FUNC:status_context] • cloudinstall.core • Choose your installation path ..
DEBUG • 11-05 23:39:54 [LINE:101, FUNC:_build_widget] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • Num items: 4, items: <BoxAdapter selectable 
flow widget <ListBox selectable box widget> height=4>
DEBUG • 11-05 23:39:58 [LINE:157, FUNC:submit] • cloudinstall.ui • Callback on : OrderedDict([('Single', <RadioButton selecta
ble flow widget 'Single' state=True>), ('Multi', <RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Multi' state=False>), ('Multi with exis
ting MAAS', <RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Multi with existing MAAS' state=False>), ('Landscape', <RadioButton selectab
le flow widget 'Landscape' state=False>)])
INFO • 11-05 23:39:58 [LINE:73, FUNC:status_context] • cloudinstall.core • Building environment
DEBUG • 11-05 23:39:58 [LINE:579, FUNC:ssh_genkey] • cloudinstall.utils • *** ssh keys exist for this user, they will be used
 instead*** If the current ssh keys are not passwordless you'll be*** required to enter your ssh key password during containe
r*** creation.
DEBUG • 11-05 23:39:58 [LINE:50, FUNC:global_exchandler] • cloudinstall.utils • Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 64, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/single_install.py", line 145, in do_install
    self.create_container_and_wait()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/single_install.py", line 64, in create_container_and_wait
    utils.container_create(self.container_name, self.userdata)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 473, in container_create
    "{0}".format(out['output']))
Exception: Unable to create container:
```

I am kinda stuck, any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/commit/f20bb562ef31d5ca595924e8352df4f20c8384cd and will make it in our experimental ppa `ppa:cloud-installer/ppa` if you wish to test that it fixes your problem. Once we finish our current testing it'll make it into the testing ppa for more real world tests. **Update**: Packages with this fix is now available in the testing ppa